# Unable to detect a Delete on the server from the client

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

In my database, I have three entities: User, List and UserList (represents a many to many relationship between user and List). In my app, I have initialized SyncContext with StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations tracking option.

```
await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(_store, StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations);
```

When my app is running for a given User, when I add a new List association for that user (by inserting a linkage record into UserList), I am able to detect this change:

```
var subscription = Client.EventManager.Subscribe<StoreOperationCompletedEvent>(async (storeEvent) => await StoreChangedEventHandler(storeEvent));

protected async Task StoreChangedEventHandler(StoreOperationCompletedEvent storeEvent) {..}
```

Now note that creating the linkage, will pull the UserList record for the User as well as the List record referenced by UserList.

When I delete this linkage record though, there is no notification of that coming to my client.

Questions: Is such notification (of deleted records) possible? If so, how do I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by enabling soft delete on the server (Azure Mobile Server SDK).  By doing that, all soft-deleted records are pulled back to the client and I can filter them out for presentation.  Works for me but may not work for everyone else.